# Is TLS required for enabling Raft based orderer in Hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Is TLS required for enabling RAFT based orderers in Hyperledger fabric . if so, whether can we use the TLS only for Orderer Cluster Communication(RAFT) or else it required the full hyperledger fabric network setup with TLS?

Comment: Yes it is mandatory for Raft based ordering service.
I don't think it is possible to use http for communication except for ordering service. But I would suggest you to use full TLS network.

Answer (score 0):

As it was posted, yes, RAFT needs TLS.  As for your second question, are you asking if peer to peer communication needs to also use TLS, I would guess no, but is there a concern with using TLS in general?